# Temp Table INLINE Indexing UNIQUE CLUSTERED vs NON-UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED, and naming requirements

Tags: sql-server, indexing, temp-tables

I find when creating a UNIQUE CLUSTERED index, I do not have to specify a name:

```
CREATE TABLE [#TEMP01]
(
    [TradeDate] DATE NOT NULL
        UNIQUE CLUSTERED([TradeDate])
);
```

I presume SQL Server is internally generating a name for the above index.

When I attempt to create a `NONUNIQUE`/`NONCLUSTERED` index, I'm compelled to supply a name:

```
CREATE TABLE [#TEMP02]
(
    [TradeDate] DATE NOT NULL
        INDEX [IX_TradeDate] NONCLUSTERED([TradeDate])
);
```

Can I create a non-unique inline index without having to supply a name?

Comment: No - the first one creates a **constraint** that is backed by an index and you just get a system generated name if you don't prefix it with `CONSTRAINT YourName`. There is no such logic for indexes not associated with constraints

Comment: Also, generally, you really **want** to give your constraints and indexes your own proper names - otherwise, they are system-named and dealing with these system-named constraints and indexes (if you need to disable / alter / drop them) is a bit of a pain - best practice: **always** explicitly **name** your database objects yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No you cannot.**

[The grammar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#full-syntax) for inline indexes defines that you must supply a name

```sql
<column_index> ::=
 INDEX index_name [ CLUSTERED | NONCLUSTERED ]
    [ WITH ( <index_option> [ ,... n ] ) ]
    .....
```

And for table-level indexes (possibly multi-column):

```sql
<table_index> ::=
{
    {
      INDEX index_name  [ UNIQUE ] [ CLUSTERED | NONCLUSTERED ]
         ( column_name [ ASC | DESC ] [ ,... n ] )
    | INDEX index_name CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE
    | INDEX index_name [ NONCLUSTERED ] COLUMNSTORE ( column_name [ ,... n ] )
    }
    [ INCLUDE ( column_name [ ,... n ] ) ]
    ....
```

What you originally referred to is not a Unique Clustered index, it's a Unique Clustered *constraint*. Constraints can indeed be defined without supplying a name, although you'd be advised to give it one. The primary difference between these two is that indexes can have `INCLUDE` columns and `WHERE` filters, constraints cannot. Both can be used as the target of a foreign key.